# Git pre-commit client-side hook. Enforce adding file via force

Tags: git, githooks, pre-commit

We have a file in git, and it's LARGE about 1GB. However, this file is generated in-engine and takes hours of full CPU usage to generate. Thus, we would like to push this up to git and have it maintained. However, it does not need to be pushed very often. In fact we almost never want to push this file unless we are building for distribution.

A few times now, someone has pushed this file up accidentally and it uses lots of LFS bandwidth and storage. I was hoping to be able to add a git pre-commit hook to make sure that this file was added to the commit by force, or just some way to double check the addition of the file.

I've never made a hook script, is there any way that I accomplish this functionality with a pre-commit hook? I am struggling to find regular documentation on the creation of these scripts and what attributes I have access to. Also, if there is an easier way to accomplish what I want, that would be super appreciated!

Comment: if you `.gitignore` the file it would require `git add -f thefile` -- is that what you mean?

Comment: This problem is actually rather common, and deserves a real solution, but Git doesn't have one. (The closest Git gets, I believe, is submodules.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this with a pre-commit hook.  Remember that *every* Git commit contains *every file* (that it contains), and a `git checkout` or `git switch` operation that extracts some commit with hash `H` first *removes* any files that are currently in Git's index and your working tree because of your current check-out of commit `G` (some other hash ID than `H`) in which some file does exist, when that file doesn't exist in commit `H`.

Hence, either the large file is in *every* commit, or it's in *no* commit: there's no real middle ground.  Git does optimize thing by literally re-using identical-content files, so if 100 commits contain version 1 of the large file, and the next 100 commits contain version 2 of the large file, then there are really only two copies of the large file in the repository, shared across 100 commits each.

A `git push` that sends a new commit that re-uses the existing large file won't re-send the large file, since the receiving Git will announce that it has existing commit `E` when your Git goes to send new commit `N`, and your Git will then see that the large-file copy in `N` matches the large-file copy in `E` and therefore doesn't need to send the file with the new commit `N`.  So it sounds like what you're really asking for—though you didn't realize it—is a way to detect whether `git push` will send a *new and different* large file, that the receiving Git currently lacks.

You can't detect this *perfectly* but you can get a decent stab at it easily in a *pre-push* hook (rather than a pre-commit hook).  Git runs the pre-push hook after your Git contacts their Git and finds out what hash ID goes with whatever existing refs they have that you're asking them to update.  The pre-push hook can read, from its standard input, the complete list of refs and hash IDs that your Git is proposing to send to their Git, along with the hash IDs they have under whatever name your Git is proposing that they update.

Using this information, you can see that, say, your Git is proposing to send to their Git the commit(s) that are reachable from your branch tip `develop` with hash ID `a123456...`.  At this time, they have, as their branch tip of *their* `develop`, a commit with hash ID `b976543...`.  Looking up this commit in your own repository, you find that `b976543` does contain the large file, with content whose hash ID is `deadcab...`, and that of all the commits in `b976543..a1234567` in your own repository, they all contain the large file with the same hash ID: in this case you'll not be sending a new copy of the large file.  Or, perhaps you *don't* have `b976543`, or `b976543` has a large file with `deadcab...` as its blob hash but `a123456...` will send the large file with contents that hash to `feeddad...` instead.  So this time your Git probably *will* send the large file, and you can force the user to, e.g., set an environment variable `I_REALLY_MEANT_TO_DO_THAT=yes` for instance.

This whole system is very klunky, and as far as I know, nobody does it like this.  Instead, the large file is considered a "build asset" and stored *outside the repository*, along with information that tells you whether this particular copy of the build asset is right for your build.  You first inspect the verification information: if it's right, you use the pre-built asset, and if not, you spend the time to build it (and then optionally deliver it to the asset server as well).

Comment: Wow! Thanks for all of the in-depth help, I really don't know much about how git works on the back end, so this is really helpful. It does seem that the solution is quite difficult and clunky, so I guess I will opt for the second answer I guess and re-ignore the file and sore it elsewhere. Thanks!